# enumeration in regular expression

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this...

```
mystring = '{#var#}status has been updated{#var#}with remark{#var#}connect with{#var#}at{#var#}transactions may be{#var#}till{#var#}'
```

I just need to number it so that it will look like this...

```
{#var1#}status has been updated{#var2#}with remark{#var3#}connect with{#var4#}at{#var5#}transactions may be{#var6#}till{#var7#}
```

This will replace the string with number 1

```
mystring.replace("{#var#}", "{#var1#}")
```

Not sure how to enumerate the number 2,3,4 till 7

Comment: You could do a simple replace (with count=1) in a loop, changing the replacing string for each iteration

Comment: maybe use f-string or .format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mystring = '{#var#}status has been updated{#var#}with remark{#var#}connect with{#var#}at{#var#}transactions may be{#var#}till{#var#}'


for i in range(mystring.count('#var#')):
    mystring = mystring.replace('#var#', f'#var{i + 1}#', 1)

print(mystring)
```

`str.replace` accepts a third argument, that specifies the number of occurrences to replace, so here it is set to `1`. So at each iteration only the first occurance of `#var#` is replaced to `f'#var{i + 1}#'` where `i` starts from `0` all the way up to the number of initial occurrences of `#var#`.

Comment: Please never give code-only answer, at explain the way you choose

Comment: Added a brief explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `iter` and `str.join` with a `list` comprehension:

```
mystring = '{#var#}status has been updated{#var#}with remark{#var#}connect with{#var#}at{#var#}transactions may be{#var#}till{#var#}'
it = iter(range(1, mystring.count('{#var#}') + 1))
print(' '.join([v[:-1] + str(next(it)) + '}' if v == '{#var#}' else v for v in mystring.replace('{#var#}', ' {#var#} ').split()]))
```

Output:

```
{#var#1}status has been updated{#var#2}with remark{#var#3}connect with{#var#4}at{#var#5}transactions may be{#var#6}till{#var#7}
```

Comment: Why not a simple range ?

Comment: @azro Edited mine.

Comment: You have over-complicated your answer, that was so much easier to understand with the loop, now it's not. readability should be a priority too ;)

Comment: @azro python_user got the for loop answer, so I tried something else.

Answer (score 0):

**Inputs**
mystring = '{#var#}status has been updated{#var#}with remark{#var#}connect with{#var#}at{#var#}transactions may be{#var#}till{#var#}'

**Steps**

1 - first replace '{#var#}' with '{}'

```
mystring = mystring.replace('{#var#}', '{}')
# mystring become => '{}status has been updated{}with remark{}connect with{}at{}transactions may be{}till{}'
```

2 - then create var_names which ranged from 1 to 8

```
var_names = [ f'{{#var1#}}' for i in range(1, 8) ]
```

3 - then .format to place your variables in string

```
mystring = mystring.format(*var_names)
```

**Outputs**

```
'{#var1#}status has been updated{#var2#}with remark{#var3#}connect with{#var4#}at{#var5#}transactions may be{#var6#}till{#var7#}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex. `finditer` can be used to used to get all the matches as regex object and required string can be constructed

```
mystring = '{#var#}status has been updated{#var#}with remark{#var#}connect with{#var#}at{#var#}transactions may be{#var#}till{#var#}'    

output_string = ""
last_match_end = 0
for i_enm, match in enumerate(re.finditer(r'\{#var#\}', mystring)):
    output_string += mystring[last_match_end:match.start()] + "{#var" + str(i_enm+1) + "#}"
    last_match_end = match.end()
output_string += mystring[last_match_end:]
```

output_string:

```
'{#var1#}status has been updated{#var2#}with remark{#var3#}connect with{#var4#}at{#var5#}transactions may be{#var6#}till{#var7#}'
```